# Need fix to show/hide a div when results found/not found using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am running this code,**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Search Bar</title>
</head>

<body>

   <style>

ul#wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}


#result {
    display: none;
}

</style>


<script>

function searchFunction() {

var ape=document.getElementById("myinput");

  var xpe = ape.value;
if (xpe.length<1) {
    alert("Search field empty !");
    return false;
  }

 else if (xpe.length<3) {
    alert("Search required minimum 3 characters");
    return false;
  }


var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myinput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    fp = document.getElementById('fullpage');
    result = document.getElementById('result')
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for(i=0 ; i< li.length; i++){
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
            li[i].style.display = "";
            ul.style.display = "block";
            fp.style.display = "none";
            result.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            li[i].style.display = "none";
            result.style.display ="block";
        }
    }
}

</script>

        <input type="text" name="search" value="" autocomplete="off" id="myinput" placeholder="Search" />

<button onclick="searchFunction()"> search </button>
<br/><br/>


<div id="result"> No results found ! </div>

    <ul id="wrapper">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Apple</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ball</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Cat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Elephant</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Fish</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Grape</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Horse</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ice-Cream</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Joker</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Kite</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Lion</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mango</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Nest</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Orange</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parrot</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Queen</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Rat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ship</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Table</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Umbrella</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Violet</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Watch</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">X-max</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Yatch</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Zebra</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<div id="fullpage">
This is a full page contents which hides when search button clicked. for future usage.
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Expexted output,**

When search clicked and found search input on list it have to show list. (this works fine) . at the same time, when there is no search keyword matches our list, then it have to show a div contains "No results found !" and next when user search suitable keyword and it matches list, it have to hide that div and show only search results.

***I tried doing `display: none;` in css and `block` in js. But, unfortunately it doesn't works. I was thinking something like toggle but, donno how to make it as am beginner in js. How to fix it ? Kindly help me with fixes.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to hide "No results found !"  inside `for` but you don't `stop for` loop when something has fined

**So your code could be like this ↓↓**

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Search Bar</title>   <style>

ul#wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}


#result {
    display: none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<script>

function searchFunction() {

var ape=document.getElementById("myinput");

  var xpe = ape.value;
if (xpe.length<1) {
    alert("Search field empty !");
    return false;
  }

 else if (xpe.length<3) {
    alert("Search required minimum 3 characters");
    return false;
  }


var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myinput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    fp = document.getElementById('fullpage');
    result = document.getElementById('result')
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');


    let founded = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i< li.length; i++){
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
            li[i].style.display = "";
            ul.style.display = "block";
            fp.style.display = "none";
            result.style.display = "none";
            founded=1;
        }
        else{ 
            li[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
    if(founded===0){
        fp.style.display = "none";
        result.style.display ="block";
    }
     
}


</script>

        <input type="text" name="search" value="" autocomplete="off" id="myinput" placeholder="Search" />

<button onclick="searchFunction()"> search </button>
<br/><br/>


<div id="result"> No results found ! </div>

    <ul id="wrapper">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Apple</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ball</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Cat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Elephant</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Fish</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Grape</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Horse</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ice-Cream</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Joker</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Kite</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Lion</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mango</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Nest</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Orange</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parrot</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Queen</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Rat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ship</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Table</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Umbrella</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Violet</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Watch</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">X-max</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Yatch</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Zebra</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<div id="fullpage">
This is a full page contents which hides when search button clicked. for future usage.
<div>

</body>
</html>
```